# Variables should fill up by certain console input in java

Tags: java

Is there any possibility in java when I type in the console 26 via scanner input that it automatically fills up t2 and t3 with their respective values in an if statement? (t2 should be 3 and t3 should be 2020)

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);         
        String s = in.nextLine(); 

        int t = Integer.parseInt(s);

        System.out.println((Arrays.asList(t, t2, t3)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your question. Is this what you ask for?

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);         
    String s = in.nextLine(); 

    int t = Integer.parseInt(s);

    if (t == 26) {
        t2 = 3; // assumed that t2 and t3 are int
        t3 = 2020;
    }
```